# Incognito effectiveness?

Tags: wireless-networking, privacy

So I go to a private high school and we have school issued laptops. I browse mostly on incognito just because there are some sites I prefered the school doesnt know I visit (like my tumblr and reddit). I know that incognito says my employer can see what sites I visit, but I only use these sites at home on my own wifi. Can my school still see my browser history? Also, when I finish school and submit my laptop back to the school, would they be able to find my history then?

Answer (score 1):

Google chrome stores incognito history and such until all browsing sessions are closed. Once they're closed, the files are deleted. Therefore, your school can use a program such as [recuva](https://www.piriform.com/recuva/download) to recover these files. However, they probably can't recover month-old incognito history.

Another way your school could spy on you would be to install spyware, but the legalities of that are a major grey area so it's doubtful that they would do so. However, it's possible.

My advice: Watch it on another computer, just to be safe.

Comment: The second point is critical. The laptop was set up and issued by your school. I has to be considered an untrusted machine since you don't know how it has been customized. It's very possible there's spyware, and browser privacy settings and even a virtual machine may not be enough to protect you.